# Different spacing in \cventry

Tags: vertical-alignment, tex-core, moderncv, cv

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{email@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/username/}
\homepage{website.github.io}           

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\vspace{-3em}

\section{Education}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{itemize}

    \item[]{\cventry{expected June 2025}{Major 1: Computer Science, Minor: Mathematics}{University}{Location, XX}{GPA: 3.95, Dean's Honors List}{\vskip 3pt \footnotesize \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed:} Operating Systems, Data Structures \& OOP, Linear Algebra \RN{1} \& \RN{2}, Discrete Mathematics, \\ Computer Architecture, Software Construction, Single \& Multi-Variable Calculus, Logic Design of Digital Circuits, \\ Computer Organization, Differential Equations, Microeconomic Theory, Symbolic Logic}{\vskip 3pt \footnotesize \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed by Summer 2025:} Algorithms and Complexity, Programming Languages, Computer Networking, \\ Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, Digital Circuit Design \& Implementation, Compiler Construction, Probability Theory, Computer Security }
}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

My question is very simple: Why is the second (vertical) spacing of 'Courses Completed by 2025' different than that of 'Courses Completed', how do I fix this, and what is the proper way to format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, put the full "description" (two parts) in the sixth parameter of `\cventry`

You are now using a seventh parameter for the second part, which has a different format.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{email@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/username/}
\homepage{website.github.io}           

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
    \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\vspace{-3em}
\section{Education}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[]\cventry{expected June 2025}{Major 1: Computer Science, Minor: Mathematics}{University}{Location, XX}{GPA: 3.95, Dean's Honors List}
    {\vskip 3pt \footnotesize%  sixth parameter <<<<<<<
            \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed:} Operating Systems, Data Structures \& OOP, Linear Algebra \RN{1} \& \RN{2}, Discrete Mathematics, \\ Computer Architecture, Software Construction, Single \& Multi-Variable Calculus, Logic Design of Digital Circuits, \\ Computer Organization, Differential Equations, Microeconomic Theory, Symbolic Logic.
            \vskip 3pt 
            \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed by Summer 2025:} Algorithms and Complexity, Programming Languages, Computer Networking, \\ Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, Digital Circuit Design \& Implementation, Compiler Construction, Probability Theory, Computer Security.
    }
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Do you know what the 7th parameter is used for? I couldn't find it in the documentation I found [here](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/manual/moderncv_userguide.pdf).

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you for your feedback! `#7` it is not documented. The definition in several of the styles starts as `\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{...` The first 6 are treated in the same way.

Comment: Got it, so more parameters than 7 is undefined. What exactly do you mean that the first 6 are treated the same way? As in the docs, you mean?

Comment: @user129393192 Sorry for the misunderstanding. `#7` is defined but its intended use is not explained  in the package document. `#4, #5` and `#6` , if supplied, are contained within a minipage (depends on the style)  along with `#3`.

Comment: Where do you get your information? I haven't found any great documentation on this.

Comment: @user129393192 Look at the `moderncvbodyiii.sty` file with a text editor around line #169 `\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{...`. This style (#3) uses a `tabular* ` to accommodate the inputs.